# How to install previous version of couchdb from a package

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I've been struggling to find any documentation on how to install previous versions of CouchDB onto Ubuntu from a package. Following any documentation such as https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.2/install/unix.html#installing leads to installing of the latest version of CouchDB always (as of today it's version 2.3). So how is it possible, for instance to install 2.1?

Tried:
apt-get install couchdb21 
apt-get install couchdb2.1
apt-get install couchdb-21
apt-get install couchdb-2.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

First you do

`apt-get policy couchdb`

to get a list of versions available and then

`apt-get install couchdb=2.1.2~trusty`